# Screen Reader within Ubuntu & Terminal

Tags: terminal, emacs, accessibility

I am forced to use Ubuntu 14.04 for a specific purpose.  However, I am blind and I need some help getting the screen reader to read inside Emacs and the Terminal.  So far I have Orca installed and turned on, but it won't read what's inside Emacs or the Terminal.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.